# AsyncTask на андроид: не работает ни в какую!

Tags: background-task, android, java, android-asynctask, многопоточность

Смодифицировал код таким образом чтобы была не простыня! Ошибка та же, не работает ни в какую! То есть на эмуляторе все нормально, на девайсе время выполнения более двух секунд!
Помогите плиз! Вот код:

```
class Sorted implements Comparable<Object> {
                  public double resball;
                  public String name;
                  public String link;
                  public double price;
                  public String key;

                public Sorted (double resball, double price, String name, String link, String key)
                  {
                    this.resball = resball;
                    this.name = name;
                    this.link = link;
                    this.price = price;
                    this.key = key;
                  }
                public int compareTo(Object obj)
                  {
                        Sorted tmp = (Sorted)obj;
                    if(this.resball < tmp.resball)
                    {
                      /* текущее меньше полученного */
                      return -1;
                    }   
                    else if(this.resball > tmp.resball)
                    {
                      return 1;
                    }
                    return 0;  
                  }

        }

        public class finish extends Activity {

         // My consts

                MyTask mt;
                int k = 1;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.finalist);

                txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
               //And others
                res1 = 9;
                res2 = 5;
                res3 = 16;
                res4 = 5;
                res5 = 7;
                res6 = 5;
                res7 = 13;
                res8 = 5;
                res9 = 20;
                res10 = 5;
                res11 = 5;
                res12 = 5;

                  }
            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();
                  mt = new MyTask();
                  mt.execute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
               super.onDestroy();
               if (mt != null) {
                   mt.cancel(true);
               }
            }

         class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, InputStream> {

            @Override
            protected InputStream doInBackground(Void... params) {
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);

                try
                {

                byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
                while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
                String jsontext = new String(buffer);
                final JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);
                JSONObject post;
                try {
                post = entries.getJSONObject(0);
                detoks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
                detoks_k = post.getString("good_code");
                detoks_op = post.getString("description");
                post = entries.getJSONObject(1);
                antioks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
                antioks_k = post.getString("good_code");
                post = entries.getJSONObject(2);
                paks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
                paks_k = post.getString("good_code");
                post = entries.getJSONObject(3);
                nutrimaks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
                nutrimaks_k = post.getString("good_code");
                    /*And Others*/

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            }
            catch (Exception je)
            {

            }

                return is;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(InputStream is) {
              super.onPostExecute(is);
              if (is == null)
                  /*I'm sorry*/
                  return;

    ***********************************************************************/    
               detoks = (detoks1*res1) + (detoks3*res2) + (detoks4*res3) 
                               + (detoks5*res4) + (detoks6*res5)+ (detoks7*res6)
                               + (detoks8*res7)+ (detoks9*res8) + (detoks10*res9)
                               + (detoks11*res10) + + (detoks12*res11)+ (detoks13*res12);
               /***********************************************************************/
               antioks = (antioks1*res1) + (antioks3*res2) + (antioks4*res3) + (antioks5*res4)
                               + (antioks6*res5)+ (antioks7*res6)+ (antioks8*res7)+ (antioks9*res8)
                               + (antioks10*res9)+ (antioks11*res10)+ (antioks12*res11)+ (antioks13*res12);
               /***********************************************************************/

                Sorted[] sortirovka = new Sorted[37];
                sortirovka[0] = new Sorted(detoks,detoks_p,detoks_n,detoks_u,detoks_k);
                sortirovka[1] = new Sorted(antioks,antioks_p,antioks_n,antioks_u,antioks_k);     
                sortirovka[2] = new Sorted(mega,mega_p,mega_n,mega_u,mega_k);
                /* And Others*/
                /* Sort array */
                Arrays.sort(sortirovka);

            txt1.setText(sortirovka[36].name);
            //And Others
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Сразу скажу делал расчеты и в back (в параметры ставил Sorted[] sortirovka)! Что делаю не так не понимаю!

Comment: так оно работает, просто долго? но работает?

скомпилировать и попробовать сам не смог - устала рука добавлять переменные вида res[1-10]. Может сделаете компилируемые сорцы?

Comment: Сейчас в качестве ответа на свой вопрос скину! Буду очень благодарен если что получится! Работает но долго поэтому девайс его убивает!

Comment: дай пример содержимого Джейсона или целиком с активностью и лэйаутом, только не портянками а файлами (или на мыло) - иначе ты нас будешь долго мучить )))

Comment: Пробовали вынести всё, что в **onPostExecute** в **doInBackground**, а оставить только **txt1.setText(str)**? Этот код точно должен выполнятся в UI потоке?
Я бы вынес всё включая сортировку в **doInBackground**, пусть он возвращает массив строк Array<String> или ваш массив **sortirovka**, а в **onPostExecute** перечислить все **setText()**.

Comment: 12 прогресс баров и 30 полей ввода. Это что же такое... боюсь андроид закрывает программу, потому что он в шоке.

Comment: Там исследоваание здоровья и куча рекомендуемых параметров! Я пытался все выводить через адаптер в GridView все то же самое! Тогда почему он на эмуляторе работает! Я просто работу закончил все на эмул работает отлично отправил заказчику он давай тестить на девайсах ни на одном не работает, вот я не знаю что делать!

Comment: тестить нужно на реальных устройствах.

btw: бады такие бады.

Comment: http://zalil.ru/34495764
Вот то что необходимо! У меня голова не хочет уже работать! Я зациклился на одном не могу даже к другим работам приступить. Все в голове эта чушь вертится а выхода точно сам не найду так как не могупереключится!
@imholynx Да все выносил в doInBack, ни в какую! Если парсинг не проводить то на девайсе все работает! Но самое ужасное ни то что он долго работает, а что это только начало парсинга еще надо описания вытаскивать для 60 товаров и их коды!((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запустил на реальном девайсе и сразу ошибку нашел. Ошибка простая. Спряталась она в этой строке

```
vden_min = Double.parseDouble(format.format(cena_min/30));
```

(там ещё несколько есть подобных).

Очень хороший пример кода с запашком. Ошибка в том, что format при преобразовании использует запятую (потому что на девайсе у заказчика видимо выставлена русская локаль или, как у меня, украинская). А parseDouble не знает об этом, ему нужна точка. А на эмуляторе с 90% вероятностью английская локаль. и там все нормально, так как format там использует точку. Если посмотреть в код детальнее, то непонятно, зачем преобразовывать снова в число.

убрал я указанную строку и две последующие и вместо них написал такое

```
vden_min = format.format(cena_min/30);
vden_k = format.format(cena_k/30);
vden_l = format.format(cena_l/30);
```

и поменял для этих трех переменных тип с double на String. и все запустилось и заработало.

Comment: Сейчас проверю если так то я дебил! Но о том что вы сказали я узнал впервые! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score -1):

Вот работающие на эмуляторе исходники!

```
 package com.melikovivan.podborbad;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

class Sorted implements Comparable<Object> {
          public double resball;
          public String name;
          public String link;
          public double price;
          public String key;

        public Sorted (double resball, double price, String name, String link, String key)
          {
            this.resball = resball;
            this.name = name;
            this.link = link;
            this.price = price;
            this.key = key;
          }
        public int compareTo(Object obj)
          {
                Sorted tmp = (Sorted)obj;
            if(this.resball < tmp.resball)
            {
              /* текущее меньше полученного */
              return -1;
            }   
            else if(this.resball > tmp.resball)
            {
              /* текущее больше полученного */
              return 1;
            }
            /* текущее равно полученному */
            return 0;  
          }

}

public class finish extends Activity {

        static String pismo;
        static String mail;

        static double detoks;
        static double antioks;
        static double paks;
        static double mega;
        static double nutrimaks;
        static double senior;
        static double osteosanum;
        static double endjoyNT;
        static double sveltform;
        static double chromvital;
        static double mediossoia;
        static double ursul;
        static double dign;
        static double biuty;
        static double nortia;
        static double neichetan;
        static double aisiberri;
        static double direset;
        static double artemida;
        static double granatin;
        static double artum;
        static double lamin;
        static double stalon;
        static double lsbalans;
        static double breinofleks;
        static double bisk;
        static double mistik;
        static double passilat;
        static double sheviton;
        static double kupers;
        static double seiftusi;
        static double kgoffsupressant;
        static double revien;
        static double senior_ledi;
        static double vineks;
        static double giper;
        static double kg_off_fetabsorber;

        /***************************************************************************************/
        static String detoks_u = "/item/show?id=17";
        static String antioks_u = "/item/show?id=14";
        static String paks_u = "/item/show?id=9";
        static String mega_u = "/item/show?id=16";
        static String nutrimaks_u = "/item/show?id=8";
        static String senior_u = "/item/show?id=23";
        static String osteosanum_u = "/item/show?id=1166";
        static String endjoyNT_u = "/item/show?id=1161";
        static String sveltform_u = "/item/show?id=19";
        static String chromvital_u = "/item/show?id=1";
        static String mediossoia_u = "/item/show?id=29";
        static String ursul_u = "/item/show?id=25";
        static String dign_u = "";
        static String biuty_u = "/item/show?id=57";
        static String nortia_u = "/item/show?id=30";
        static String neichetan_u ="/item/show?id=5";
        static String aisiberri_u = "/item/show?id=1165";
        static String direset_u = "/item/show?id=1163";
        static String artemida_u = "/item/show?id=1133";
        static String granatin_u = "/item/show?id=1144";
        static String artum_u = "/item/show?id=27";
        static String lamin_u = "/item/show?id=26";
        static String stalon_u = "/item/show?id=24";
        static String lsbalans_u = "/item/show?id=1143";
        static String breinofleks_u = "/item/show?id=22";
        static String bisk_u = "/item/show?id=3";
        static String mistik_u = "/item/show?id=12";
        static String passilat_u = "/item/show?id=13";
        static String sheviton_u = "/item/show?id=4";
        static String kupers_u = "/item/show?id=18";
        static String seiftusi_u = "/item/show?id=15";
        static String kgoffsupressant_u = "/item/show?id=20";
        static String revien_u = "/item/show?id=10";
        static String senior_ledi_u = "";
        static String vineks_u = "/item/show?id=7";
        static String giper_u = "/item/show?id=11";
        static String kg_off_fetabsorber_u = "/item/show?id=21";

        /***************************************************************************************/
        static double detoks_p= 0;
        static double antioks_p= 0;
        static double paks_p= 0;
        static double mega_p= 0;
        static double nutrimaks_p= 0;
        static double senior_p= 0;
        static double osteosanum_p= 0;
        static double endjoyNT_p= 0;
        static double sveltform_p= 0;
        static double chromvital_p= 0;
        static double mediossoia_p= 0;
        static double ursul_p= 0;
        static double dign_p= 0;
        static double biuty_p= 0;
        static double nortia_p= 0;
        static double neichetan_p= 0;
        static double aisiberri_p = 0;
        static double direset_p= 0;
        static double artemida_p= 0;
        static double granatin_p= 0;
        static double artum_p= 0;
        static double lamin_p= 0;
        static double stalon_p= 0;
        static double lsbalans_p= 0;
        static double breinofleks_p= 0;
        static double bisk_p= 0;
        static double mistik_p= 0;
        static double passilat_p= 0;
        static double sheviton_p= 0;
        static double kupers_p= 0;
        static double seiftusi_p= 0;
        static double kgoffsupressant_p= 0;
        static double revien_p= 0;
        static double senior_ledi_p= 0;
        static double vineks_p= 0;
        static double giper_p= 0;
        static double kg_off_fetabsorber_p= 0;
        /***************************************************************************************/

        // Названия продуктов
        static String detoks_n = "Детокс";
        static String antioks_n = "Антиокс";
        static String paks_n = "Пакс";
        static String mega_n = "Мега";
        static String nutrimaks_n = "Нутримакс";
        static String senior_n = "Сеньор";
        static String osteosanum_n = "ОстеоСанум";
        static String endjoyNT_n = "Энджой НТ";
        static String sveltform_n = "Свелтформ";
        static String chromvital_n = "Хромвитал";
        static String mediossoia_n = "Медисоя";
        static String ursul_n = "Урсул";
        static String dign_n = "Дигн";
        static String biuty_n = "Бьюти";
        static String nortia_n = "Нортия";
        static String neichetan_n ="Нейчетан";
        static String aisiberri_n = "Ай Си Берри";
        static String direset_n = "DiReset";
        static String artemida_n = "Артемида";
        static String granatin_n = "Гранатин";
        static String artum_n = "Артум";
        static String lamin_n = "Ламин";
        static String stalon_n = "Сталон";
        static String lsbalans_n = "ЛС-Баланс";
        static String breinofleks_n = "Брейн ОФ";
        static String bisk_n = "Биск";
        static String mistik_n = "Мистик";
        static String passilat_n = "Пассилат";
        static String sheviton_n = "Шевитон";
        static String kupers_n = "Куперс";
        static String seiftusi_n = "Сэйф ту си";
        static String kgoffsupressant_n = "КГ-Офф Саппрессант";
        static String revien_n = "Ревьен";
        static String senior_ledi_n = "Сеньор Леди";
        static String vineks_n = "Винекс";
        static String giper_n = "Гипер";
        static String kg_off_fetabsorber_n = "КГ-Офф Фэтабсорбер";

        // Названия продуктов
        static String detoks_op = "Детокс";
        static String antioks_op = "Антиокс";
        static String paks_op = "Пакс";
        static String mega_op = "Мега";
        static String nutrimaks_op = "Нутримакс";
        static String senior_op = "Сеньор";
        static String osteosanum_op = "ОстеоСанум";
        static String endjoyNT_op = "Энджой НТ";
        static String sveltform_op = "Свелтформ";
        static String chromvital_op = "Хромвитал";
        static String mediossoia_op = "Медисоя";
        static String ursul_op = "Урсул";
        static String dign_op = "Дигн";
        static String biuty_op = "Бьюти";
        static String nortia_ = "Нортия";
        static String neichetan_op ="Нейчетан";
        static String aisiberri_op = "Ай Си Берри";
        static String direset_op = "DiReset";
        static String artemida_op = "Артемида";
        static String granatin_op = "Гранатин";
        static String artum_op = "Артум";
        static String lamin_op = "Ламин";
        static String stalon_op = "Сталон";
        static String lsbalans_op = "ЛС-Баланс";
        static String breinofleks_op = "Брейн ОФ";
        static String bisk_op = "Биск";
        static String mistik_op = "Мистик";
        static String passilat_op = "Пассилат";
        static String sheviton_op = "Шевитон";
        static String kupers_op = "Куперс";
        static String seiftusi_op = "Сэйф ту си";
        static String kgoffsupressant_op = "КГ-Офф Саппрессант";
        static String revien_op = "Ревьен";
        static String senior_ledi_op = "Сеньор Леди";
        static String vineks_op = "Винекс";
        static String giper_op = "Гипер";
        static String kg_off_fetabsorber_op = "КГ-Офф Фэтабсорбер";

        // Переменные содержащие коды товаров магазине

        // Названия продуктов
        static String detoks_k;
        static String antioks_k;
        static String paks_k;
        static String mega_k;
        static String nutrimaks_k;
        static String senior_k;
        static String osteosanum_k;
        static String endjoyNT_k;
        static String sveltform_k;
        static String chromvital_k;
        static String mediossoia_k;
        static String ursul_k;
        static String dign_k;
        static String biuty_k;
        static String nortia_k;
        static String neichetan_k;
        static String aisiberri_k;
        static String direset_k;
        static String artemida_k;
        static String granatin_k;
        static String artum_k;
        static String lamin_k;
        static String stalon_k;
        static String lsbalans_k;
        static String breinofleks_k;
        static String bisk_k;
        static String mistik_k;
        static String passilat_k;
        static String sheviton_k;
        static String kupers_k;
        static String seiftusi_k;
        static String kgoffsupressant_k;
        static String revien_k;
        static String senior_ledi_k;
        static String vineks_k;
        static String giper_k;
        static String kg_off_fetabsorber_k;

        // Переменные содержащие в себе былы по каждой из систем
        static double res1;
        static double res2;
        static double res3;
        static double res4;
        static double res5;
        static double res6;
        static double res7;
        static double res8;
        static double res9;
        static double res10;
        static double res11;
        static double res12;
        // Первая система коэффициенты продутов
        double detoks1 = 16;
        double antioks1 = 15;
        double paks1 = 14;
        double mega1 = 13;
        double nutrimaks1 = 12;
        double senior1 = 11;
        double osteosanum1 = 10;
        double endjoy1 = 9;
        double sveltform1 = 8;
        double chromvital1 = 7;
        double mediosoia1 = 6;
        double ursul1 = 5;
        double dign1 = 4;
        double biuty1 = 3;
        double nortia1 = 2;
        double neichetan1 = 1;

        // Вторая система- коэффициенты продуктов
        double aisiberri2 = 16;
        double antioks2 = 15;
        double detoks2 = 14;
        double nutrimaks2 = 13;
        double mega2 = 12;
        double paks2 = 11;
        double senior2 = 10;
        double sveltform2 = 9;
        double direset2 = 8;
        double chromvital2 = 7;
        double mediosoia2 = 6;
        double biuty2 = 5;
        double nortia2 = 4;
        double artemida2 = 3;
        double granatin2 = 2;
        double osteosanum2 = 1;

        // Третья система- коэффициенты продуктов для мужчин
        double detoks3 = 16;
        double antioks3 = 15;
        double ursul3 = 14;
        double mega3 = 13;
        double paks3 = 12;
        double direset3 = 11;
        double nutrimaks3 = 10;
        double sveltform3 = 9;
        double senior3 = 8;
        double artum3 = 7;
        double lamin3 = 6;
        double stalon3 = 5;
        double lsbalans3 = 4;
        double granatin3 = 3;
        double breinofleks3 = 2;
        double dign3 = 1;

        // 4-я система- коэффициенты продуктов
        double antioks4 = 16;
        double nutrimaks4 = 15;
        double paks4 = 14;
        double mega4 = 13;
        double senior4 = 12;
        double detoks4 = 11;
        double direset4 = 10;
        double sveltform4 = 9;
        double chromvital4 = 8;
        double ursul4 = 7;
        double dign4 = 6;
        double granatin4 = 5;
        double bisk4 = 4;
        double biuty4 =3;
        double mistik4  = 2;
        double passilat4 = 1;

        // 5-я система- коэффициенты продуктов
        double antioks5 = 16;
        double detoks5 = 15;
        double biuty5 = 14;
        double mega5 = 13;
        double sheviton5 = 12;
        double paks5 = 11;
        double sveltform5 = 10;
        double chromvital5 = 9;
        double senior5 = 8;
        double nutrimaks5 = 7;
        double endjoy5 = 6;
        double granatin5 = 5;
        double neichetan5 = 4;
        double kupers5 = 3;
        double seiftusi5 = 2;
        double mistik5 = 1;

        // 6-я систмема - кф. продуктов
        double antioks6 = 16;
        double detoks6 = 15;
        double paks6 = 14;
        double senior6 = 13;
        double mega6 = 12;
        double nutrimaks6 = 11;
        double sveltform6 = 10;
        double kupers6 = 9;
        double chromvital6 = 8;
        double neichetan6 = 7;
        double dign6 = 6;
        double direset6 = 5;
        double granatin6 = 4;
        double ursul6 = 3;
        double lsbalans6 = 2;
        double kgoffsupressant6 = 1;

        //7-я система -кф. продуктов
        double nutrimaks7 = 16;
        double antioks7 = 15;
        double senior7 = 14;
        double mega7 = 13;
        double chromvital7 = 12;
        double detoks7 = 11;
        double osteosanum7 = 10;
        double lsbalans7 = 9;
        double paks7 = 8;
        double granatin7 = 7;
        double bisk7 = 6;
        double biuty7 = 5;
        double revien7 = 4;
        double neichetan7 = 3;
        double senior_ledi7 = 2;
        double kupers7 = 1;

        //8-я система кф-продуктов

        double antioks8 = 16;
        double nutrimaks8 = 15;
        double senior8 = 14;
        double mega8 = 13;
        double paks8 = 12;
        double vineks8 = 11;
        double granatin8 = 10;
        double sveltform8 = 9;
        double detoks8 = 8;
        double lsbalans8 = 7;
        double giper8 = 6;
        double dign8 = 5;
        double neichetan8 = 4;
        double mistik8 = 3;
        double passilat8 = 2;
        double nortia8 = 1;

        //9-я система

        double antioks9 = 16;
        double detoks9 = 15;
        double paks9 = 14;
        double senior9 = 13;
        double mega9 = 12;
        double nutrimaks9 = 11;
        double chromvital9 = 10;
        double sveltform9 = 9;
        double ursul9 = 8;
        double granatin9 = 7;
        double vineks9 = 6;
        double direset9 = 5;
        double kupers9 = 4;
        double revien9 = 3;
        double dign9 = 2;
        double neichetan9 = 1;

        //10-я система

        double detoks10 = 16;
        double antioks10 = 15;
        double direset10 = 14;
        double mega10 = 13;
        double paks10 = 12;
        double senior10 = 11;
        double chromvital10 = 10;
        double nutrimaks10 = 9;
        double sveltform10 = 8;
        double ursul10 = 7;
        double dign10 = 6;
        double kupers10 = 5;
        double granatin10 = 4;
        double bisk10 = 3;
        double biuty10 = 2;
        double neichetan10 = 1;

        //11-я система
        double antioks11 = 16;
        double detoks11 = 15;
        double sveltform11 = 14;
        double mega11 = 13;
        double chromvital11 = 12;
        double paks11 = 11;
        double senior11 = 10;
        double direset11 = 9;
        double nutrimaks11 = 8;
        double kgoffsupressant11 = 6;
        double kg_off_fetabsorber11 = 7;
        double dign11 = 5;
        double kupers11 = 4;
        double lamin11 = 3;
        double biuty11 = 2;
        double bisk11 = 1;

        //12-я система
        double detoks12 = 16;
        double antioks12 = 15;
        double paks12 = 14;
        double mega12 = 13;
        double chromvital12 = 12;
        double nutrimaks12 = 11;
        double senior12 = 10;
        double sveltform12 = 9;
        double granatin12 = 8;
        double breinofleks12 = 7;
        double dign12 = 6;
        double neichetan12 = 5;
        double vineks12 = 4;
        double mistik12 = 3;
        double giper12 = 2;
        double passilat12 = 1;

        //13-я система

        double paks13 = 16;
        double antioks13 = 15;
        double senior13 = 14;
        double breinofleks13 = 13;
        double nutrimaks13 = 12;
        double detoks13 = 11;
        double sveltform13 = 10;
        double chromvital13 = 9;
        double seiftusi13 = 8;
        double giper13 = 7;
        double mistik13 = 6;
        double passilat13 = 5;
        double revien13 = 4;
        double granatin13 = 3;
        double neichetan13 = 2;
        double dign13 = 1;

        double cena_min;
        double cena_k;
        double cena_l;

        double vden_min;
        double vden_k;
        double vden_l;

        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;
        TextView txt4;
        TextView txt5;
        TextView txt6;
        TextView txt7;
        TextView txt8;
        TextView txt9;
        TextView txt10;
        TextView txt11;
        TextView txt12;
        TextView txt13;
        TextView txt14;
        TextView txt15;
        TextView txt16;
        TextView txt17;
        TextView txt18;
        TextView txt19;        
        TextView txt20;
        TextView txt21;
        TextView txt22;
        TextView txt23;
        TextView txt24;
        TextView txt25;
        TextView txt26;
        TextView txt27;
        TextView txt28;
        TextView txt29;
        Button bt;

        ProgressBar pb1;
        ProgressBar pb2;
        ProgressBar pb3;
        ProgressBar pb4;
        ProgressBar pb5;
        ProgressBar pb6;
        ProgressBar pb7;
        ProgressBar pb8;
        ProgressBar pb9;
        ProgressBar pb10;
        ProgressBar pb11;
        ProgressBar pb12;

        static WebView myBrowser;

        SharedPreferences sPref;
        MyTask mt;
        int k = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finalist);

        pb1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb2 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        pb3 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        pb4 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
        pb5 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar5);
        pb6 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar6);
        pb7 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar7);
        pb8 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar8);
        pb9 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar9);
        pb10 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar10);
        pb11 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar11);
        pb12 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar12);

        pb1.setMax(20);
        pb2.setMax(20);
        pb3.setMax(20);
        pb4.setMax(20);
        pb5.setMax(20);
        pb6.setMax(20);
        pb7.setMax(20);
        pb8.setMax(20);
        pb9.setMax(20);
        pb10.setMax(20);
        pb11.setMax(20);
        pb12.setMax(20);

        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button but1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

        txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        txt4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        txt5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        txt6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        txt7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        txt8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        txt9 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        txt10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        txt11 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        txt12 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView14);

        txt13 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txt14 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        txt15 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView16);
        txt16 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView17);
        txt17 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView18);
        txt18 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView19);
        txt19 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView20);
        txt20 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        txt21 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        txt22 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView23);
        txt23 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView24);
        txt24 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        txt25 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView26);
        txt26 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView27);
        txt27 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView28);
        txt28 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView29);
        res1 = 9;
        res2 = 5;
        res3 = 16;
        res4 = 5;
        res5 = 7;
        res6 = 5;
        res7 = 13;
        res8 = 5;
        res9 = 20;
        res10 = 5;
        res11 = 5;
        res12 = 5;
          txt1.setClickable(true);

          (findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    bt.setText("MIF SOFT");
                }
              });

          (findViewById(R.id.button4)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mail});
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ИММУНИТЕТ-ВАША ЛИЧНАЯ ЗАЩИТА");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(pismo));
                    emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
                }
              });

          }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
          mt = new MyTask();
          mt.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       if (mt != null) {
           mt.cancel(true);
       }
    }

 class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, InputStream> {

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(Void... params) {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);

        try
        {

        byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
        String jsontext = new String(buffer);
        final JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);
        JSONObject post;
        try {
        post = entries.getJSONObject(0);
        detoks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        detoks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        detoks_op = post.getString("description");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(1);
        antioks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        antioks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(2);
        paks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        paks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(3);
        nutrimaks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        nutrimaks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(4);
        sveltform_k = post.getString("good_code");
        sveltform_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        post = entries.getJSONObject(5);
        chromvital_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        chromvital_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(6);
        seiftusi_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        seiftusi_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(7);
        senior_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        senior_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(8);
        lsbalans_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        lsbalans_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(11);
        senior_ledi_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        senior_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(16);
        endjoyNT_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        endjoyNT_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(17);
        osteosanum_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        osteosanum_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(19);
        direset_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        direset_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(21);
        vineks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        vineks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(22);
        breinofleks_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        breinofleks_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(23);
        sheviton_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        sheviton_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(24);
        neichetan_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        neichetan_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(26);
        mega_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        mega_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(27);
        bisk_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        bisk_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(28);
        revien_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        revien_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(29);
        giper_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        giper_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(30);
        mistik_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        mistik_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(31);
        passilat_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        passilat_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(32);
        ursul_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        ursul_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(33);
        lamin_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        lamin_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(34);
        artum_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        artum_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(35);
        biuty_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        biuty_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(36);
        nortia_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        nortia_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(37);
        granatin_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        granatin_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(38);
        stalon_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        stalon_k = post.getString("good_code");
        post = entries.getJSONObject(39);
        mediossoia_k = post.getString("good_code");
        mediossoia_p = Double.parseDouble(post.getString("price"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    }
    catch (Exception je)
    {

    }

        return is;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream is) {
      super.onPostExecute(is);
      if (is == null)
          /*I'm sorry*/
          return;

      // if(com.melikovivan.podborbad.provp.polp > 0) {
       if(k > 0) {
               /***********************************************************************/    
       detoks = (detoks1*res1) + (detoks3*res2) + (detoks4*res3) 
                       + (detoks5*res4) + (detoks6*res5)+ (detoks7*res6)
                       + (detoks8*res7)+ (detoks9*res8) + (detoks10*res9)
                       + (detoks11*res10) + + (detoks12*res11)+ (detoks13*res12);
       /***********************************************************************/
       antioks = (antioks1*res1) + (antioks3*res2) + (antioks4*res3) + (antioks5*res4)
                       + (antioks6*res5)+ (antioks7*res6)+ (antioks8*res7)+ (antioks9*res8)
                       + (antioks10*res9)+ (antioks11*res10)+ (antioks12*res11)+ (antioks13*res12);
       /***********************************************************************/
       paks = (paks1*res1) + (paks3*res2) + (paks4*res3) + (paks5*res4)+ (paks6*res5)
                           + (paks7*res6)+ (paks8*res7)+ (paks9*res8)+ (paks10*res9)+ (paks11*res10)
                           + (paks12*res11)+ (paks13*res12);
       /*********************************************************************/
              nutrimaks = (nutrimaks1*res1) + (res3*nutrimaks2) + (res3*nutrimaks4) + (res4*nutrimaks5)
                           + (res5*nutrimaks6)+ (res6*nutrimaks7)+ (res7*nutrimaks8)+ (res8*nutrimaks9)
                           + (res9*nutrimaks10)+ (res10*nutrimaks11)+ (res11*nutrimaks12)+ (res12*nutrimaks13);
             /*********************************************************************/
           senior = (res1*senior1) + (res2*senior3) + (res3*senior4) + (res4*senior5)
                        + (res5*senior6)+ (res6*senior7)+ (res7*senior8)+ (res8*senior9)
                        + (res9*senior10)+ (res10*senior11)+ (res11*senior12)+ (res12*senior13);
           /*********************************************************************/
              sveltform = (sveltform1*res1) + (sveltform3*res2)+ (sveltform4*res3)+ (sveltform5*res4)
                           + (sveltform6*res5) + (sveltform8*res7)+ (sveltform9*res8)
                           + (sveltform10*res9)+ (sveltform11*res10)+ (sveltform12*res11)+ (sveltform13*res12);
              /*********************************************************************/
               mega = (mega1*res1) + (mega3*res2)+ (mega4*res3)+ (mega5*res4)
                           + (mega6*res5) + (mega8*res7)+ (mega9*res8)
                           + (mega10*res9)+ (mega11*res10)+ (mega12*res11);
            /*********************************************************************/
            osteosanum = (res1*osteosanum1) + (res7*osteosanum7);
            /*********************************************************************/
            breinofleks = breinofleks3*res2 + res12*breinofleks13;
            /*********************************************************************/
            chromvital = (sveltform1*res1) + (chromvital4*res3)+ (chromvital5*res4)
                            + (chromvital6*res5) + (chromvital9*res8) + (chromvital10*res9)+ (chromvital11*res10)
                            + (chromvital12*res11)+ (chromvital13*res12);
            /*********************************************************************/
            endjoyNT = (endjoy1*res1) + (endjoy5*res4);
            /*********************************************************************/
            direset = (direset3*res2) + (direset4*res3)+ (direset6*res5)+ (direset9*res8)
                            + (direset10*res9)+ (direset11*res11);
            /*********************************************************************/
            biuty = (biuty1*res1) + (biuty4*res3)+ (biuty5*res4)+ (biuty7*res6)
                            + (biuty10*res9)+ (biuty11*res10);
            /*********************************************************************/
            ursul = (ursul1*res1) + (ursul4*res3)+ (ursul6*res5)+ (ursul9*res8)+ (ursul10*res9);
            /*********************************************************************/
            dign = (dign1*res1) + (dign3*res2)+ (dign4*res3)+ (dign6*res5)+ (dign8*res7)
                            + (dign9*res8)+ (dign10*res9)+ (dign11*res10)+ (dign12*res11)+ (dign13*res12);
               /*********************************************************************/
            lsbalans = (lsbalans3*res2) + (lsbalans6*res5) + (lsbalans7*res6) + (lsbalans8*res7);
            /*********************************************************************/
            sheviton = sheviton5*res4;
            /*********************************************************************/
            nortia = (nortia1*res1) + (nortia8*res7);
            /*********************************************************************/
            neichetan = (neichetan1*res1) + (neichetan5*res4)+ (neichetan6*res5)
                            + (neichetan7*res6)+ (neichetan8*res7)+ (neichetan9*res8) + (neichetan10*res9)
                            + (neichetan12*res11)+ (neichetan13*res12);
            /*********************************************************************/
            mediossoia = (mediosoia1*res1);
            /*********************************************************************/
            stalon = stalon3*res2;
            /*********************************************************************/
            senior_ledi = senior_ledi7*res6;
            /*********************************************************************/
            seiftusi = (seiftusi5*res4) + (seiftusi13*res12);
            /*********************************************************************/
            lamin = (lamin3*res2) + (lamin11*res10);
            /*********************************************************************/
            mistik = (mistik4*res3) + (mistik5*res4) + (mistik8*res7);
            /*********************************************************************/
            kg_off_fetabsorber = kg_off_fetabsorber11*res10;
            /*********************************************************************/
            kgoffsupressant = (kgoffsupressant11*res10) + (kgoffsupressant6*res5);
            /*********************************************************************/
            bisk = (bisk4*res3) + (bisk10*res9) + (bisk11*res10) + (bisk7*res6);
            /*********************************************************************/
            revien = (revien7*res6) + (revien9*res8) + (revien13*res12);
            /*********************************************************************/
            passilat = (passilat4*res3) + (passilat8*res7)+ (passilat12*res11) + (passilat13*res12);
            /*********************************************************************/
            giper = (giper8*res7) + (giper12*res11) + (giper13*res12);
            /*********************************************************************/
            vineks = (vineks8*res7) + (vineks9*res8) + (vineks12*res11);
            /*********************************************************************/
            granatin = (granatin3*res2) + (granatin4*res3)+ (granatin5*res4)+ (granatin6*res5)+ (granatin7*res6)
                            + (granatin8*res7)+ (granatin9*res8)+ (granatin10*res9)+ (granatin12*res11)+ (granatin13*res12);
            /*********************************************************************/
            kupers = (kupers5*res4) + (kupers6*res5) + (kupers7*res6) + (kupers9*res8) + (kupers10*res9) + (kupers11*res10);
            artum = artum3*res2;

        }
      /* if(com.melikovivan.podborbad.provp.polp < 1) {*/
       if(k < 1) {
               /***********************************************************************/
                detoks = (detoks1*res1) + (detoks2*res2) + (detoks4*res3) 
                            + (detoks5*res4) + (detoks6*res5)+ (detoks7*res6)
                            + (detoks8*res7)+ (detoks9*res8) + (detoks10*res9)
                            + (detoks11*res10) + + (detoks12*res11)+ (detoks13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/

                antioks = (antioks1*res1) + (antioks2*res2) + (antioks4*res3) + (antioks5*res4)
                            + (antioks6*res5)+ (antioks7*res6)+ (antioks8*res7)+ (antioks9*res8)
                            + (antioks10*res9)+ (antioks11*res10)+ (antioks12*res11)+ (antioks13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/

                paks = (paks1*res1) + (paks2*res2) + (paks4*res3) + (paks5*res4)+ (paks6*res5)
                                + (paks7*res6)+ (paks8*res7)+ (paks9*res8)+ (paks10*res9)+ (paks11*res10)
                                + (paks12*res11)+ (paks13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                nutrimaks = (nutrimaks1*res1) + (res2*nutrimaks2) + (res3*nutrimaks4) + (res4*nutrimaks5)
                                + (res5*nutrimaks6)+ (res6*nutrimaks7)+ (res7*nutrimaks8)+ (res8*nutrimaks9)
                                + (res9*nutrimaks10)+ (res10*nutrimaks11)+ (res11*nutrimaks12)+ (res12*nutrimaks13);
                /*********************************************************************/
                senior = (res1*senior1) + (res2*senior2) + (res3*senior4) + (res4*senior5)
                                + (res5*senior6)+ (res6*senior7)+ (res7*senior8)+ (res8*senior9)
                                + (res9*senior10)+ (res10*senior11)+ (res11*senior12)+ (res12*senior13);
                /*********************************************************************/
                sveltform = (sveltform1*res1) + (sveltform2*res2)+ (sveltform4*res3)+ (sveltform5*res4)
                                + (sveltform6*res5) + (sveltform8*res7)+ (sveltform9*res8)
                                + (sveltform10*res9)+ (sveltform11*res10)+ (sveltform12*res11)+ (sveltform13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                mega = (mega1*res1) + (mega2*res2)+ (mega4*res3)+ (mega5*res4)
                                + (mega6*res5) + (mega8*res7)+ (mega9*res8)
                                + (mega10*res9)+ (mega11*res10)+ (mega12*res11);
                /*********************************************************************/
                aisiberri = res2*aisiberri2;
                /*********************************************************************/
                osteosanum = (res1*osteosanum1) + (res2*osteosanum2) + (res7*osteosanum7);
                /*********************************************************************/
                breinofleks = res12*breinofleks13;
                /*********************************************************************/
                chromvital = (sveltform1*res1) + (chromvital2*res2)+ (chromvital4*res3)+ (chromvital5*res4)
                                + (chromvital6*res5) + (chromvital9*res8) + (chromvital10*res9)+ (chromvital11*res10)
                                + (chromvital12*res11)+ (chromvital13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                endjoyNT = (endjoy1*res1) + (endjoy5*res4);
                /*********************************************************************/
                direset = (direset2*res2) + (direset4*res3)+ (direset6*res5)+ (direset9*res8)
                                + (direset10*res9)+ (direset11*res11);
                /*********************************************************************/
                biuty = (biuty1*res1) + (biuty2*res2)+ (biuty4*res3)+ (biuty5*res4)+ (biuty7*res6)
                                + (biuty10*res9)+ (biuty11*res10);
                /*********************************************************************/
                ursul = (ursul1*res1) + (ursul4*res3)+ (ursul6*res5)+ (ursul9*res8)+ (ursul10*res9);
                /*********************************************************************/
                dign = (dign1*res1) + (dign4*res3)+ (dign6*res5)+ (dign8*res7)
                                + (dign9*res8)+ (dign10*res9)+ (dign11*res10)+ (dign12*res11)+ (dign13*res12);
                   /*********************************************************************/
                lsbalans = (lsbalans6*res5) + (lsbalans7*res6) + (lsbalans8*res7);
                /*********************************************************************/
                sheviton = sheviton5*res4;
                /*********************************************************************/
                nortia = (nortia1*res1) + (nortia2*res2) + (nortia8*res7);
                /*********************************************************************/
                neichetan = (neichetan1*res1) + (neichetan5*res4)+ (neichetan6*res5)
                                + (neichetan7*res6)+ (neichetan8*res7)+ (neichetan9*res8) + (neichetan10*res9)
                                + (neichetan12*res11)+ (neichetan13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                mediossoia = (mediosoia1*res1) + (mediosoia2*res2);
                /*********************************************************************/
                artemida = artemida2*res2;
                /*********************************************************************/
                senior_ledi = senior_ledi7*res6;
                /*********************************************************************/
                seiftusi = (seiftusi5*res4) + (seiftusi13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                lamin = lamin11*res10;
                /*********************************************************************/
                mistik = (mistik4*res3) + (mistik5*res4) + (mistik8*res7);
                /*********************************************************************/
                kg_off_fetabsorber = kg_off_fetabsorber11*res10;
                /*********************************************************************/
                kgoffsupressant = (kgoffsupressant11*res10) + (kgoffsupressant6*res5);
                /*********************************************************************/
                bisk = (bisk4*res3) + (bisk10*res9) + (bisk11*res10) + (bisk7*res6);
                /*********************************************************************/
                revien = (revien7*res6) + (revien9*res8) + (revien13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                passilat = (passilat4*res3) + (passilat8*res7)+ (passilat12*res11) + (passilat13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                giper = (giper8*res7) + (giper12*res11) + (giper13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                vineks = (vineks8*res7) + (vineks9*res8) + (vineks12*res11);
                /*********************************************************************/
                granatin = (granatin2*res2) + (granatin4*res3)+ (granatin5*res4)+ (granatin6*res5)+ (granatin7*res6)
                                + (granatin8*res7)+ (granatin9*res8)+ (granatin10*res9)+ (granatin12*res11)+ (granatin13*res12);
                /*********************************************************************/
                kupers = (kupers5*res4) + (kupers6*res5) + (kupers7*res6) + (kupers9*res8) + (kupers10*res9) + (kupers11*res10);
       }

        Sorted[] sortirovka = new Sorted[37];
        sortirovka[0] = new Sorted(detoks,detoks_p,detoks_n,detoks_u,detoks_k);
        sortirovka[1] = new Sorted(antioks,antioks_p,antioks_n,antioks_u,antioks_k);     
        sortirovka[2] = new Sorted(mega,mega_p,mega_n,mega_u,mega_k);
        sortirovka[3] = new Sorted(paks,paks_p,paks_n,paks_u,paks_k);
        sortirovka[4] = new Sorted(ursul,ursul_p,ursul_n,ursul_u,ursul_k);
        sortirovka[5] = new Sorted(senior,senior_p,senior_n,senior_u,senior_k);
        sortirovka[6] = new Sorted(nutrimaks,nutrimaks_p,nutrimaks_n,nutrimaks_u,nutrimaks_k);
        sortirovka[7] = new Sorted(sveltform,sveltform_p,sveltform_n,sveltform_u,sveltform_k);
        sortirovka[8] = new Sorted(aisiberri,aisiberri_p,aisiberri_n,aisiberri_u,aisiberri_k);
        sortirovka[9] = new Sorted(osteosanum,osteosanum_p,osteosanum_n,osteosanum_u,osteosanum_k);
        sortirovka[10] = new Sorted(breinofleks,breinofleks_p,breinofleks_n,breinofleks_u,breinofleks_k);
        sortirovka[11] = new Sorted(chromvital,chromvital_p,chromvital_n,chromvital_u,chromvital_k);
        sortirovka[12] = new Sorted(endjoyNT,endjoyNT_p,endjoyNT_n,endjoyNT_u,endjoyNT_k);
        sortirovka[13] = new Sorted(direset,direset_p,direset_n,direset_u,direset_k);
        sortirovka[14] = new Sorted(biuty,biuty_p,biuty_n,biuty_u,biuty_k);
        sortirovka[15] = new Sorted(dign,dign_p,dign_n,dign_u,dign_k);
        sortirovka[16] = new Sorted(lsbalans,lsbalans_p,lsbalans_n,lsbalans_u,lsbalans_k);
        sortirovka[17] = new Sorted(sheviton,sheviton_p,sheviton_n,sheviton_u,sheviton_k);
        sortirovka[18] = new Sorted( nortia, nortia_p, nortia_n, nortia_u, nortia_k);
        sortirovka[19] = new Sorted( neichetan, neichetan_p, neichetan_n, neichetan_u, neichetan_k);
        sortirovka[20] = new Sorted( mediossoia, mediossoia_p, mediossoia_n, mediossoia_u, mediossoia_k);
        sortirovka[21] = new Sorted( artemida, artemida_p, artemida_n, artemida_u, artemida_k);
        sortirovka[22] = new Sorted( senior_ledi, senior_ledi_p, senior_ledi_n, senior_ledi_u, senior_ledi_k);
        sortirovka[23] = new Sorted( seiftusi, seiftusi_p, seiftusi_n, seiftusi_u, seiftusi_k);
        sortirovka[24] = new Sorted( lamin, lamin_p, lamin_n, lamin_u, lamin_k);
        sortirovka[25] = new Sorted( mistik, mistik_p, mistik_n, mistik_u, mistik_k);
        sortirovka[26] = new Sorted( kg_off_fetabsorber, kg_off_fetabsorber_p, kg_off_fetabsorber_n, kg_off_fetabsorber_u, kg_off_fetabsorber_k);
        sortirovka[27] = new Sorted( kgoffsupressant, kgoffsupressant_p, kgoffsupressant_n, kgoffsupressant_u, kgoffsupressant_k);
        sortirovka[28] = new Sorted( bisk, bisk_p, bisk_n, bisk_u, bisk_k);
        sortirovka[29] = new Sorted( revien, revien_p, revien_n, revien_u, revien_k);
        sortirovka[30] = new Sorted( passilat, passilat_p, passilat_n, passilat_u, passilat_u);
        sortirovka[31] = new Sorted( giper, giper_p, giper_n, giper_u, giper_k);
        sortirovka[32] = new Sorted( vineks, vineks_p, vineks_n, vineks_u, vineks_k);
        sortirovka[33] = new Sorted( granatin, granatin_p, granatin_n, granatin_u, granatin_k);
        sortirovka[34] = new Sorted( kupers, kupers_p, kupers_n, kupers_u, kupers_k);
        sortirovka[35] = new Sorted( artum, artum_p, artum_n, artum_u, artum_k);
        sortirovka[36] = new Sorted( stalon, stalon_p, stalon_n, stalon_u, stalon_k);
        /* Сортировка массива */
        Arrays.sort(sortirovka);
      sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String domen = sPref.getString("domen", "welness4you.ru");
        String consult_code = sPref.getString("consult_code", "Vision");
        mail = sPref.getString("mail", "vanyamelikov@yandex.ru");

        String my_name = sPref.getString("name", "Меликов Иван");
            cena_min = sortirovka[36].price + sortirovka[35].price + sortirovka[34].price + sortirovka[33].price;
            cena_k = cena_min + sortirovka[32].price + sortirovka[31].price + sortirovka[30].price + 
                    + sortirovka[29].price;
            cena_l = cena_k + sortirovka[28].price + sortirovka[27].price + sortirovka[26].price + sortirovka[25].price + 
                    sortirovka[24].price + sortirovka[23].price + sortirovka[22].price + sortirovka[21].price;
            NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
            format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

            vden_min = Double.parseDouble(format.format(cena_min/30));
            vden_k = Double.parseDouble(format.format(cena_k/30));
            vden_l = Double.parseDouble(format.format(cena_l/30));

            /******************************Формирование ссылок в корзину***********************************************/
            String buy_m = "<a href=http://client.visionshop.me/AutoFillCart.aspx?ID=" + consult_code +"&countryCode=RU&Goods=" 
            + sortirovka[36].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[35].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[34].key + "/1@"+ sortirovka[33].key + "/1";
            String buy_k = buy_m + "@" + sortirovka[32].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[31].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[30].key + "/1@"
                    + sortirovka[29].key + "/1";
            String buy_l = buy_k+ "@" + sortirovka[28].key + "/1@"+ sortirovka[27].key + "/1@"+ sortirovka[26].key + "/1@"
                    + sortirovka[25].key + "/1@"+ sortirovka[24].key + "/1@"+ sortirovka[23].key + "/1@"+ sortirovka[22].key + "/1@"
                    + sortirovka[21].key + "/1";

          pismo = 
                    "<body>" +
                            "<p>Результаты исследования Вашего здоровья:</p>" +
                            "<p>Рекомендуемые для Вас продукты компании Vision:</p>" +
                            "<p>Минимальная:</p>" + 
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[36].link + ">"+sortirovka[36].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[35].link + ">"+sortirovka[35].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[34].link + ">"+sortirovka[34].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[33].link + ">"+sortirovka[33].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>Цена:" + cena_min +  "</p>" +
                            "<p>В день:" + vden_min + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + buy_m +">" + "<strong><em>КУПИТЬ</em></strong></a></p>" +
                            "<p>Классическая:</p>" + 
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[36].link + ">"+sortirovka[36].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[35].link + ">"+sortirovka[35].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[34].link + ">"+sortirovka[34].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[33].link + ">"+sortirovka[33].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[32].link + ">"+sortirovka[32].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[31].link + ">"+sortirovka[31].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[30].link + ">"+sortirovka[30].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[29].link + ">"+sortirovka[29].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>Цена:" + cena_k +  "</p>" +
                            "<p>В день:" + vden_k + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + buy_k +">" + "<strong><em>КУПИТЬ</em></strong></a></p>" +
                            "<p>Люкс:</p>" + 
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[36].link + ">"+sortirovka[36].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[35].link + ">"+sortirovka[35].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[34].link + ">"+sortirovka[34].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[33].link + ">"+sortirovka[33].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[32].link + ">"+sortirovka[32].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[31].link + ">"+sortirovka[31].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[30].link + ">"+sortirovka[30].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[29].link + ">"+sortirovka[29].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[28].link + ">"+sortirovka[28].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[27].link + ">"+sortirovka[27].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[26].link + ">"+sortirovka[26].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[25].link + ">"+sortirovka[25].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[24].link + ">"+sortirovka[24].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[23].link + ">"+sortirovka[23].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[22].link + ">"+sortirovka[22].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + "<a href=http://" + domen + sortirovka[21].link + ">"+sortirovka[21].name+"</a>" + "</p>" +
                            "<p>Цена:" + cena_l +  "</p>" +
                            "<p>В день:" + vden_l + "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + buy_l +">" + "<strong><em>КУПИТЬ</em></strong></a></p>" + 
                            "<p>Чтобы заказать продукты нажмите на Заказать в выбранной Вами программе.<br />" + 
                            "Вы окажетесь в официальном магазине компании и сможете сразу  <strong>ОФОРМИТЬ ДОСТАВКУ</strong> своего заказа на дом!</p>" +
                            "<p>&nbsp;</p>" + 
                            "<p>Ваш персональный консультант:</p>" +
                            "<p>С уважением," + my_name +  "</p>" +
                            "<p>" + mail +"</p>" +
                            "</body>";

    txt1.setText(sortirovka[36].name);
    txt2.setText(sortirovka[35].name);
    txt3.setText(sortirovka[34].name);
    txt4.setText(sortirovka[33].name);
    bt.setText(String.valueOf(cena_min));

    txt5.setText(sortirovka[36].name);
    txt6.setText(sortirovka[35].name);
    txt7.setText(sortirovka[34].name);
    txt8.setText(sortirovka[33].name);
    txt9.setText(sortirovka[32].name);
    txt10.setText(sortirovka[31].name);
    txt11.setText(sortirovka[30].name);
    txt12.setText(sortirovka[29].name);

    txt13.setText(sortirovka[36].name);
    txt14.setText(sortirovka[35].name);
    txt15.setText(sortirovka[34].name);
    txt16.setText(sortirovka[33].name);
    txt17.setText(sortirovka[32].name);
    txt18.setText(sortirovka[31].name);
    txt19.setText(sortirovka[30].name);
    txt20.setText(sortirovka[29].name);
    txt21.setText(sortirovka[28].name);
    txt22.setText(sortirovka[27].name);
    txt23.setText(sortirovka[26].name);
    txt24.setText(sortirovka[25].name);
    txt25.setText(sortirovka[24].name);
    txt26.setText(sortirovka[23].name);
    txt27.setText(sortirovka[22].name);
    txt28.setText(sortirovka[21].name);
    pb1.setProgress((int) res1);
    pb2.setProgress((int) res2);
    pb3.setProgress((int) res3);
    pb4.setProgress((int) res4);
    pb5.setProgress((int) res5);
    pb6.setProgress((int) res6);
    pb7.setProgress((int) res7);
    pb8.setProgress((int) res8);
    pb9.setProgress((int) res9);
    pb10.setProgress((int) res10);
    pb11.setProgress((int) res11);
    pb12.setProgress((int) res12);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийКарпов, привет из будущего. Файлопомойки, бывает, мрут.

Comment: @Arhad а причем здесь я?